# Using a taxonomy value as part of a post URL

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy, urls

I'm working on a Real Estate site using the following permalink format for properties:

> http://www.site.com/property/1330-5th-avenue 
>   (property is a custom post type for listings)

How can I modify the permalink for these posts to

> http://www.site.com/new-york/1330-5th-avenue 
>   (being new New York a term which is associated with custom taxonomy City)

I have been researching but I really need help. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add or replace this to your register_taxonomy (in functions.php):

```
'query_var' => 'city',
'rewrite' => true
```

Then append this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('post_link', 'city_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'city_permalink', 10, 3); 
function city_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
  if (strpos($permalink, '%city%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
  // Get post
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if (!$post) return $permalink;
  // Get taxonomy terms
  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'city');   
  if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
  else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-rated';
  return str_replace('%city%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

[Here](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks) you can find a more detailed description.